# how can i convert a date in javascript to string

Tags: javascript, date

i have a javascript method that takes a date:

```
  convert(new Date("02/20/2010");
```

how can i let convert return "02/20/2010" as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d=new Date("02/20/2010");

(d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();

2/20/2010
```

or just print it without passing it to Date constructor?

```
alert("02/20/2010")
```

Comment: yeah i tried this , and i noticed that the month is always giving me an answer < the actual month by 1!! y is that? y did u put +1 to the month?

Comment: That is by design actually, month starts from 0 (Zero), more info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp "w3schools Date getMonth")

Comment: The month is 0 indexed. 0 is January. 11 is December. It's just the way it is :)

Answer (score 2):

The output of `Date("02/20/2010")` is something like `Thu Apr 22 2010 15:15:51 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` which by itself is string.

There are some in-built Date/Time manipulation functions which might be of use to you

`toDateString()` method

```
d=new Date("02/20/2010");
d.toDateString();
==> Tue Feb 02 2010
```

`d.toUTCString()`  =>  Fri, 19 Feb 2010 18:30:00 GMT

But if `"02/20/2010"` is what you want as output, you can go with the above answers.

**By the way why do you want a method that gives out the output same as the input ?**